# How to complete a query in Rails with a deep condition?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to query a database based on a deep condition. As an example, I would like to find all of the people whose primary pet has a specific breed name:

Person > Pet > Breed > Name

The models might look like this.

```
class Person
  has_many pets
  attr_accessor :primary_pet
end

class Pet
  belongs_to Person
  has_one Breed
end

class Breed
  # no belonging relationship
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

Now I could do:

```
Person.find_each do |person|
  puts person if primary_pet.breed.name == 'Norwich Terrier'
end
```

but I want to figure out the proper query syntax for doing this with a where method. The following does not work:

```
Person.where(primary_pet.breed.name: 'Norwich Terrier').find_each do |person|
  puts person
end
```

Comment: This will do the trick: `Person.includes(pets: :breed).where(breeds: { name: 'Norwich Terrier' })`

Comment: https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/advanced-querying-belongs-to

Answer (score 1):

I formalized the model relationships with minor edit, and ended up with this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  attr_accessor :primary_pet
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :breed
end

class Breed < ActiveRecord::Base
  # no belonging relationship
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

The best query that I came up with (that actually worked) was this:

```
Person.joins(pets: :breed).where(breeds: { name: 'Norwich Terrier' }).where("people.primary_pet = pets.id")
```

This says to join the relationship for `pets` and to `breeds`.  This allows using the `breeds` structure to filter for 'Norwich Terrier'.  And to finish it off, to additionally filter by primary_pet_id related to pets.id.

That should get you what you asked for in the question.

Here's how I tested it:

```
breed_names = ["Beagle", "Collie", "Norwich Terrier", "German Shepard", "Dachshund"]
people_names = ["Barbara", "Connie", "Paula", "Gerald", "Dave"]

# Add breeds
breed_names.each {|name| Breed.create!(name: name) }
# Add people
people_names.each {|name| Person.create!(name: name) }

# Add some pets
people_names.each do |name|
  person = Person.find_by(name: name)
  breed_names.sample(3).each do |breed|
    breed = Breed.find_by(name: breed_name)
    Pet.create!(breed_id: breed.id, person_id: person.id)
  end
end

# Assign the primary_pet for each person
Person.all.each {|person| pet = person.pets.first ; person.update!(primary_pet: pet) if pet }

# List all people and their pets by breed
Person.all.each do |person|
  puts "#{person.name}: #{person.pets.map {|pet| pet.breed.name}}"
end

# List all people and their primary pet breed
Person.all.each do |person|
  puts "#{person.name}: #{person.primary_pet ? person.primary_pet.breed.name : ''}"
end

# Run the query
Person.joins(pets: :breed).where(breeds: { name: 'Norwich Terrier' }).where("people.primary_pet = pets.id")
```

Comment: Doesnt it throw an error `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'breeds' was not found on Person` ? And as far as I know its better to use [includes method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) instead of joins. Correct me if Im wrong

Comment: @MartinZinovsky the `joins` and `includes` methods will often do basically the same thing (minor differences in SQL generated), but they exist for entirely different purposes.  `joins` is used for explicitly joining tables and providing additional querying power for other query methods (e.g. `where).  `includes` is used for implicit joins intended specifically for eager loading associations.  I wouldn't use them interchangeably, because there could be undesirable side effects.  `includes` will often work in place of `joins`, but not always.  Great question! :D